# eclipse egit github OSX configuration

Tags: eclipse, git, macos, github

I'm using Eclipse 2018.12 with egit on a Mac and am unable to update a remote repository on github.

I created a local repository on git, updated that repository, and created a repository on Github.  The egit documentation from eclipse describes using "Team -> Remote -> Push" in Windows Preferences to enter the location of the remote repository, but that command sequence isn't in the Mac version of Eclipse.  The Mac allows "Team -> Git -> Configuration -> Repository Settings tab", but I'm not sure of the correct settings there.

The message I get when I try to Push the project to Github is "error: refusing to create funny ref 'master' remotely".  I suspect my settings in the Repository Settings (above).  Any advice?

Comment: On Macs the Preferences menu is in the 'Eclipse' menu rather than 'Windows'

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  But there's not an exact correlation between the menu options once you get into the Preferences.